# Fatal error: 'nDCAPI.h' file not found

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
/Desktop/aug_9/iOSSample/iOSSample/test.m:11:10: fatal error: 'nDCAPI.h' file not found
#include <nDCAPI.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I got this error even i include the file in my project Right click on project and add file to project and selected the file and selected Destination and folders i create folder references for any added folders.

for adding the file into the project!

I got this error
/Desktop/aug_9/iOSSample/iOSSample/test.m:11:10: fatal error: 'nDCAPI.h' file not found
    #include 
             ^
    1 error generated.

Comment: I make Yes to always search User Path! now i do not getting this error!

Comment: Are you importing the file correctly in the code? `#import "nDCAPI.h"` instead of `#import <nDCAPI.h>`

Comment: that is difference in #import "nDCAPI.h" instead of #import <nDCAPI.h>

Comment: I don't understand what you said? Did it help?

Comment: when i change from always search User Path to YES i do not get error!    but i do not know what difference between #import "nDCAPI.h"  and #import <nDCAPI.h>  is both are same?